# Image overlay not rendering in IE11 with SSL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ssl, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to get an image overlay to render in IE11 with SSL enabled, much like clicking 'Free Download" in https://www.avast.com/en-us/index (only works while using Chrome).  Currently, its working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but will not render in IE11.  The page dims, but no overlay is rendered, despite the fact I can see the same javascript being executed in the debugger as Chrome and FF.

Using normalize.css v3.0.2

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.js-overlay').hide();

$('.js-download-button').click(function(){
    $('.js-overlay .overlay-download').hide();
    $('.js-overlay .overlay-download-ie').hide();

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.js-overlay').fadeIn();      
        }, 3000);
        $('.js-overlay .overlay-download-ie').show();
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {

        return;
    } else  {               // If another browser, return 0
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.js-overlay').fadeIn();      
        }, 3000);
        $('.js-overlay .overlay-download').show();
    }
});

$('.js-overlay').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
});
```